# Pandas Average of row ignoring 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
           AD1        AD2        AD3        AD4        AD5
1            0          0          0          0          0
2            0          0          0          0          0
3            0          0          0          0          0
4            0          0          0          0          0
5            0          0          0          0          0
..         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
497  138099424  126282256          0  197637664          0
498   90184696   53508360   90254688   66803036   57421672
499   41476688   54889712   36677268   33858400   50282272
500   26322476   27609302   26245020   20566374   23664970
501  595136256  241994400  489766144  314901408  730741120
```

I need to find the mean of each row, ignoring instances of 0. My initial plan was to replace 0 with NaN and then get the mean excluding NaN.

I tried to replace `0` with `NaN`, however this didn't work, and the DataFrame still contained 0. I tried:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

The second issue is when I tried to calculate the mean, even knowing `0` would be included, the mean could not be calculated. I used:

```
df = df.assign(mean=df.mean(axis=1))
```

The outcome was:

```
           AD1        AD2        AD3        AD4        AD5  mean
1            0          0          0          0          0   NaN
2            0          0          0          0          0   NaN
3            0          0          0          0          0   NaN
4            0          0          0          0          0   NaN
5            0          0          0          0          0   NaN
..         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...   ...
497  138099424  126282256          0  197637664          0   NaN
498   90184696   53508360   90254688   66803036   57421672   NaN
499   41476688   54889712   36677268   33858400   50282272   NaN
500   26322476   27609302   26245020   20566374   23664970   NaN
501  595136256  241994400  489766144  314901408  730741120   NaN
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to replace 0 with NaN, however this didn't work, and the DataFrame still contained 0. I tried:

Convert your string values to numeric

```
df['mean'] = df.astype(float).replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
           AD1        AD2        AD3        AD4        AD5         mean
1            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
2            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
3            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
4            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
5            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
497  138099424  126282256          0  197637664          0  154006448.0
498   90184696   53508360   90254688   66803036   57421672   71634490.4
499   41476688   54889712   36677268   33858400   50282272   43436868.0
500   26322476   27609302   26245020   20566374   23664970   24881628.4
501  595136256  241994400  489766144  314901408  730741120  474507865.6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mask` + `mean`:

```
df['mean'] = df.mask(df==0).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           AD1        AD2        AD3        AD4        AD5         mean
1            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
2            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
3            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
4            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
5            0          0          0          0          0          NaN
497  138099424  126282256          0  197637664          0  154006448.0
498   90184696   53508360   90254688   66803036   57421672   71634490.4
499   41476688   54889712   36677268   33858400   50282272   43436868.0
500   26322476   27609302   26245020   20566374   23664970   24881628.4
501  595136256  241994400  489766144  314901408  730741120  474507865.6
```

Comment: When I do this, it still returns the dataframe I posted second.

Comment: @lcfields maybe the dtypes are different; try: `df=df.astype(float)` first

Answer (score 2):

Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), not `fillna`:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
```

For the mean:

```
df['mean'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1)
```

or, as copy:

```
df.assign(mean=df.replace(0, np.nan).mean(axis=1))
```

Comment: The `df.replace` does not work either

Comment: @lcfields are you sure you have integers? Check the types

Comment: the type is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`. I also did `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the 0 values with a wrong function. You should really be looking at `df.replace()` function:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
# or
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The `df.replace` does not work either

Comment: @lcfields Can you double check your data type? You might be having string in your dataframe instead of float or int.

Answer (score 0):

To replace `0` numeric values by **NaN** you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=pandas%20dataframe%20replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace) and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=pandas%20dataframe%20dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna), by following this methods:

`df.replace(0, pd.NaT)`

after call method above, you will replace **NaN** *values*

`df.dropna()`

finally **mean** calculated

`df["mean"] = df.mean(axis=1)`